# Flutter Search bar not displaying all the information

Tags: flutter, dart, search

Can anyone help me I have a problem my search bar is not working. Typed the text to search for, put in the search box, but no results came up, my code runs fine. no errors Occurs but there is a problem Some of them are malfunctioning, making the search bar unusable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYA9M.png)

```
class view_problem extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  State<view_problem> createState() => _view_problemState();
}

class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      getAllProblem();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

      void _filterSearch(String query) {
        List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
        for (var item in problemlist) {
         if (item.toString().contains(query.toString())) {
            problemlist.add(item);
          }
        }
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 12, 134),
            title: const Text('information'),
          ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _filterSearch(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.area,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                              trailing: Text(
                                problem.status,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is some part of my code not working or misbehaving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change you have the name problemList repeated in the method and also you have not have setState.

```
void _filterSearch(String query) {
List<problemModel> filteredList = [];
  for (var item in problemlist) {
    if (item.toString().contains(query.toString())) {
      filteredList.add(item);
    }
  }
  setState(() {
    problemlist = filteredList;
  });
}
```

there is a bunch of ways to solve the list, other way to do it is having 2 list one to set the value of the complete list, the second the search list, having a controller for the text edit, a `_controller = TextEditingController()` add a listener in initState() and add a use the previews method but with

```
setState(() {
    _searchList = filteredList;
  });
```

and then inside the build in the listBuilder a if statement, if the `_controller.text==''` the list is the complete list, else show the `_searchList`